# How to clear thread context in Spring boot Tomcat scenario?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

We implement a `HandlerInterceptor` to setup the MDC thread context data inside the `preHandle` method.

Then we use this data for logging and metrics purposes.

But if we clear the MDC data with `MDC.clear()` inside the `afterCompletion` method, the valuable information is lost for the metrics handler that come after this. I'm speaking of `WebMvcTagsProvider` in particular, but I suppose this applies for all sorts of use cases.

Since there is a thread pool, a thread will eventually be reused and contain an MDC context from the previous HTTP request, which is very bad!

So how can I "wrap" the usage of a thread in a setup and finalize method?
Ideally this would be a generic solution. I don't want to change existing code. The goal is, that new incoming requests have no access to the previous MDC context.

I already know how to solve this in the Java EE world, e.g.:

```java
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.USER + 1)
public class MdcClearFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(
        ContainerRequestContext requestContext,
        ContainerResponseContext responseContext) {
        MDC.clear();
    }
}
```

So how do I do the same in the Spring Boot world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `HandlerInterceptor`s are all within a Servlet context, they are unable to break out.

So the solution was to use a servlet `Filter` with order `Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE`.

```java
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class MDCClearFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, 
                         ServletResponse response, 
                         FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        MDC.clear();
    }
}
```